# Автоматически обновить коллекцию MONGODB при наступлении даты

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Сервер на express.js подключен к MONGOdb. Есть коллекция, к примеру Users. Моделька User-a имеет поле status с type:String и поле date с type:Date. У некоторых юзеров поле date имеет значение даты до сегодняшнего дня. Как сделать так, чтобы без конкретных запросов с клиента, а прямо на сервере , так сказать в режиме live, в прямом эфире, обновить User-ов, когда их поле date будет соответствовать , к примеру, сегодняшнему дню?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение с использованием *Scheduler*.

Подходят npm пакеты node cron или Node Schedule. С их помощью можно на сервере, проверять с определенной периодичностью данные и менять их если надо.